# Extjs combobox autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I have an editor grid and a combobox is one of its fields.
The combobox uses a json store.
Here is the combobox code:

```
var patternCmb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({ //combobox for workers
    store:  dsPatterns,
    valueField: 'pid',
    displayField: 'pname',
    typeAhead:true, 
    lazyRender:true,
    forceSelection:true,
    minChars: 2, 
    valueNotFoundText:"not found",
    editable: true,
    triggerAction: 'all' 
});
```

After typing the third character the FIRST (not correct) value of the store is selected. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Set  `mode: 'local'` in your combobox.
2. Ensure that you have `autoLoad: true` in your dsPatterns (store).

Comment: I think `mode` has changed to `queryMode` in ExtJS 4.

Comment: I don't think the OP was talking about ExtJS 4.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make note of that for anyone looking at this question today trying to figure out how to do it.